# Using SQL Server 2022 with SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server

Can we use SQL Server 2022 with SharePoint 2013. I am trying to find evaluation versions of old SQL Server such as 2008 R2, 2012 and 2014 but they are not available. Seems like Microsoft only keep current version of SQL Server evaluation on website and removes old version.
So I want to know if we can use SQL Server 2022 Enterprise with SharePoint 2013 Enterprise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, SharePoint 2013 does not support Microsoft SQL Server 2022. The highest version it supports is SQL Server 2014:

[Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint 2013](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/install/hardware-software-requirements-2013#software-requirements)

If you would like to use newer versions of SQL Server with SharePoint, I would recommend upgrading to a newer version of SharePoint.